# Trying to stub an HTTP call with Mocha & Sinon. Received Error: TypeError: get expected to yield, but no callback was passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, axios, mocha.js

I have been practicing stubbing with [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) & [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) to master this & later on I'll unit test my real implementation of a `HTTP` call.

I have created a `function` using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to fetch all `todos` & exported to be stub like so:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const getAllTodos = () => {
  return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response => response);
};

module.exports = { getAllTodos };
```

Then I tried stubbing it like so:

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const axios = require('axios');

const { getAllTodos } = require('correct/path/to/method');

describe('Testing the todos HTTP call', () => {
  before(() => {
      sinon.stub(axios, 'get').yields(null, null, JSON.stringify([
        {
          userId: 1,
          id: 1,
          title: "delectus aut autem",
          completed: false
          },
      ]))
    });

    after(() => {
      axios.get.restore();
    });

  it('should return all todos', done => {
    getAllTodos().then(todos => {
      todos.data.forEach(todo => {
        expect(todo).to.have.property('userId');
        expect(todo).to.have.property('id');
        expect(todo).to.have.property('title');
        expect(todo).to.have.property('completed');
      });
      done();
    }).catch(done, done);
  });
});
```

However, I get the following error:

```
1) Testing the todos HTTP call
       should return all todos:
     TypeError: get expected to yield, but no callback was passed. Received [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos]
```

If I unit test the `function` without stubbing it. It works like a charm. This is the unit test without being stubbed:

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { getAllTodos } = require('correct/path/to/method');

describe('Testing the todos HTTP call', () => {
  it('should return all todos', done => {
    getAllTodos().then(todos => {
      todos.data.forEach(todo => {
        expect(todo).to.have.property('userId');
        expect(todo).to.have.property('id');
        expect(todo).to.have.property('title');
        expect(todo).to.have.property('completed');
      });
      done();
    }).catch(done, done);
  });
});
```

I get the `function` properly passing with the right assertions:

```
Testing the todos HTTP call
    ✓ should return all todos (169ms)
```

How can I fix this? What I'm doing wrong? I need a beginner-friendly explanation to translate this solution to my own implementation.

**EDIT:**

I have been trying other ways to stub the `HTTP` call, it works with the internet, but once I closed my internet... the `stub` fails. This is my latest code:

```
describe('Testing the todos HTTP call', () => {
  let stub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    stub = sinon.stub({ getAllTodos }, 'getAllTodos');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    stub.restore();
  });

  it('should return all todos with the right properties', () => {
    const mockedResponseObj = {
      userId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: 'This is title',
      completed: true,
    };

    stub
      .withArgs('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .returns(Promise.resolve(mockedResponseObj));

    const result = getAllTodos('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');

    expect(result.data[0]).to.have.property('userId');
    expect(result.data[0]).to.have.property('id');
    expect(result.data[0]).to.have.property('title');
    expect(result.data[0]).to.have.property('completed');
  });
});
```

& the exported `function` latest code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const getAllTodos = url => {
  return axios.get(url).then(response => response);
};

module.exports = { getAllTodos };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to unit tested the `getALLTodos` method by stubbing `Axios` & it's `GET` method instead like so:

```
describe('Testing the todos HTTP call', () => {
  let stub;

  const mockedResponseObj = {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: 'This is title',
    completed: true,
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    stub = sinon.stub(axios, 'get').resolves(mockedResponseObj);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    stub.restore();
  });

  it('should return all todos with the right properties', done => {
    getAllTodos('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(res => {
      expect(res.data[0]).to.have.keys(Object.keys(mockedResponseObj));
    });
    done();
  });
});
```